# Toggle .dimBackground() method on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to dim the background of my main content while accenting on a sidebar that needs to show up from the right, so I am using the **[dim-background](https://github.com/andywer/jquery-dim-background)** jquery plugin. I want to toggle the `.dimBackground()` method for my element when I click its trigger. It adds a div with the class of `dimbackground-curtain` and it simply stacks this div when I click the trigger, making everything darker and darker.

I want to be able to toggle both the sidebar and the dimming above the main content. And if possible, to be able to toggle it if I click outside the sidebar as well.

Sample code from the fiddle:

```
$('.trigger').click(function() {
  $('.sidebox').toggleClass('sidebox-open');
  $('.sidebox').dimBackground({
    darkness: 0.35
  });
});
```

There is no CDN that provides this [**library**](https://github.com/andywer/jquery-dim-background), however, here is the **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kcujd8t8/)** describing my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [**Usage**](https://github.com/andywer/jquery-dim-background) guide, there's a `.undim` method.
It seems that `.dimBackground` does not toggle, so you will have to store the state on your end and invoke either `.dimBackground` or `.undim` depending on the state and switch it.

Example:

```
var dimmed = false;
$('.trigger').click(function() {
  var $sidebox = $('.sidebox'); //avoid searching the element twice
  if(dimmed){
      $sidebox.removeClass('sidebox-open');
      $sidebox.undim();
      dimmed = false;
  } else {
      $sidebox.addClass('sidebox-open');
      $sidebox.dimBackground({
        darkness: 0.35
      });
      dimmed = true;
  }
});
```

Comment: This is the exact thing that I need to see in code.

Comment: Thank you very much! I also want to know how can I toggle it if I click outside of the sidebar?

Comment: You will need to find a place for the variable ``dimmed`` that is accessible by both scopes. How to do that is hard to tell, that depends on your overall architecture of the project. Also, a cleaner way to do it would be to create a new function ``toggleSidebox`` that does all the work. This avoids duplicate code because you can call that method in both click handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this and check if it gives you a similar functionality:

```
$('.trigger').click(function() {
   $('.sidebox').toggleClass('sidebox-open');
   if($('.sidebox').attr('class') == "sidebox sidebox-open"){
       $('.sidebox').fadeTo( "slow" , 1);
   }
   else{
       $('.sidebox').fadeTo( "slow" , 0);
   }
   /*$('.sidebox').dimBackground({
      darkness: 0.35
      });*/
});
```